# How to update input on new binding with previous value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I mean, if during runtime there’s a new binding to a certain `inputAction`, such as:

```
inputAction.performed += ctx => Function(ctx.ReadValue<float>());
```

And suppose that before this new binding the player was already holding this input to `1f`, and continues after being bound. This new input binding knows nothing about this held value, because no change was made to the input, and so no callback was called.

This, however, is problematic. I would like previously held inputs to execute callbacks even though no change was made.

For now, the input gets eaten until a change is made.

Is there a way to configure this? Or the only alternative would be to code it manually?

Comment: 10000% untested but what if you made a local variable say "i" which had a value you wanted depending on some calculation or lookup table - whatever - and then yu do myfunc(i); it will remember the value of i

Comment: @BugFinder what are you talking about?

Comment: clearly about as clear as your question if it didnt make sense then i got the wrong end of what exactly youre asking

Comment: @BugFinder we're not understanding each other, the question is unclear? I'm talking about inputs getting eaten when no change is made and a new binding is bound. I edited the question.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? **I would like previously held inputs to execute callbacks even though no change was made.** This is just a workaround that you thought of. But that is not your end goal. What do you want to do with it? What is your problem and what do you expect to happen? We constantly get posts of people wanting Unity to do something other than it's supposed to because they have "some" ideas or expectations, but often, a solution can be achieved in a simpler way, other then rewriting a whole module like the Input subsystem :) Let's be pragmatic.

Comment: @TheNomad I'm asking if there's a way to do this already, not to change how Unity works. I think it's pretty logical to expect that new bound actions will be getting the current value of the input.

Comment: @TheNomad what happens is, right arrow is pressed, axis set to 1, callback is called with 1 as parameter. New callback is bound, no call to such function with 1 as parameter, so the module's action whose callback has been recently bound to the input thinks the axis is at 0, which is not true, and forces the player to unpress and press again the right arrow for it to work.

Comment: @GuillemVS So let's see if I understand. Your very explicit scenario is this: from your POV, the way Unity works is fine, you get your CB with 1, but *IF* while holding the arrow key, you add a new CB, but the new CB is not executed and you want the second one to fire?

Comment: @TheNomad it's not a trigger though, I'm talking about an axis, such as with movement. You'd do right and left arrow ranging from -1 to 1, if a new CB is set while holding, no callback is made to this new CB with the current value, and so from the player's POV it looks like it's eating the input, until you stop holding in that direction and press it again.

Comment: I didn't say it is a trigger. That is normal behavior and it's part of the design of any programming language, not just C#. A callback is fired only per function call. It's very close to an immutable concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not simply change the way events work in c# .. what you want basically means: In the moment you attach the listener also make a poll check to the action state and if it is currently pressed/triggered then invoke the method immediately as well.

I think you can do this like e.g.

```
inputAction.performed += ctx => Function(ctx.ReadValue<float>());

if(inputAction.inProgress)
{
    Function(inputAction.ReadValue<float>());
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, except you either mistyped or misunderstood my question, but it's not `triggered`, but rather `inProgress`, due to it being an axis, not a button press, what gets eaten. I'm giving you the answer, but change this part if you will.

Comment: @GuillemVS you keep hanging on the "triggering" part. Triggering in code is not the same as a Unity trigger. Same as "firing". Or "invoking". Focus on the answer, trust us, we understand if you explain properly or answer questions, don't just hang on irrelevant things :) A listener is the best approach, rather than polling as that might imply abusing `Update()` by most.

Comment: @TheNomad the property `triggered`, does not return true when player is holding, because I assume it only returns true when it's pressed in the frame in which is pressed. My desired condition is that of `inProgress`, this resolves my issue.

Comment: @GuillemVS only on the phone so didn't have the exact API at hand, indeed as you say `isTriggered` seems to be the equivalent to `Input.GetKeyDown` (only true in the first frame) while `inProgress` is more the equivalent to `Input.GetKey` (true continuously while pressed), adopted the answer